# Create an On-touch expand ListView in android

Tags: android, listview, expand

How to create a listview in android so that when I want to click on of the list items, it expand to show more details?

Answer (score 0):

Just override the methods below

```
     setOnChildClickListener(ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener onChildClickListener)
 setOnGroupClickListener(ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener onGroupClickListener)
```

This inside this, you can to whatever you need, when you click on child or group item

Answer (score 0):

You can use the expandable list methods